# Target webkit browsers for css3 exclusion

Tags: html, css

I have some text in a  paragraph

> Aliquam tempor interdum volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc nibh
>   elit, sagittis nec libero a, pretium fermentum sapien. Aliquam eu
>   risus eu dui varius elementum. Curabitur ut ex luctus, egestas dui sit
>   amet, malesuada lectus.

I am trying to use css exclusions in the paragraph using the code below but it does not seem to work.

```
#exclusion {
    position: absolute;
    background: lightblue;
    -webkit-wrap-flow:clear !important;
}
```

Am i targeting webkit for exclusion correctly?.

Update

If you are not familiar with css exclusions, here are some examples http://galjot.si/css-exclusions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am i targeting webkit for exclusion correctly?.

No.

In general, new features in webkit today are added behind configuration flags instead of being vendor prefixes. (This is a consequence of developers using vendor prefixes in production).

Even when webkit browsers added new features behind vendor prefixes, you can't just use it and expect it to work.

See [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-exclusions). Currently only IE and Edge support Exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

there is no `wrap-flow` support in chrome, even with prefixes

http://caniuse.com/#search=wrap-flow